# Adding a line using sed

Tags: regex, sed

Can't seem to find the right way to do this, despite checking my regex in a reg checker.

Given a text file containing, amongst others, this entry:

```
zone    "example.net"    {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.example.net";
        allow-transfer { x.x.x.x;y.y.y.y; };
        also-notify { x.x.x.x;y.y.y.y; };
};
```

I want to add lines after the also-notify line, for that domain specifically.

So using this sed command string:

```
sed '/"example\.net".*?also-notify.*?};/a\nxxxxxxx/s' named.conf.local
```

I thought should work to add 'xxxxxxx' after the line. But nope. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that sed supports non-greedy quantifiers like `*?`?

Comment: `sed` takes one line at a time. You can't search through lines like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With POSIX sed, you can use the `a` for append command with an escaped literal new line:

```
$ sed  '/^[[:blank:]]*also-notify/ a\
NEW LINE' file
```

With GNU sed, `a` is slightly more natural since the new line is assumed:

```
$ gsed  '/^[[:blank:]]*also-notify/ a NEW LINE' file
```

The issue with the `sed` in your example is two fold.

The first is any `sed` regex cannot be for a multi-line match as in `example\.net".*?also-notify.*?`. That is more of a perl type match. You would need to use a range operator for the start as in:

```
$ sed  '/"example\.net/,/also-notify/{
       /^[[:blank:]]*also-notify/ a\
    NEW LINE 
    }' file
```

The second issue is the `\n` in the appended text. With POSIX sed, the `\n` is not supported in any context. With GNU sed, the new line is assumed and the `\n` is out of context (if immediately after the `a`) and interpreted as an escaped literal `n`. You can use `\n` with GNU sed after 1 character but not immediately after. In POSIX sed, leading spaces of the appended line will always be stripped.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help on this.

```
awk -v new_lines="new_line here" '/also-notify/{flag=1;print new_lines} /^};/{flag=""} !flag'  Input_file
```

In case you want to edit Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code too. Also `print new_lines` here new_lines is a variable you could print the new liens directly too in there.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close already. Just use a range (`/pattern/,/pattern/{ #commands }`) to select the text you want to operate on and then use `/pattern/a/\ ...` to add the line you want.

```
/"example\.net"/,/also-notify/{
/also-notify/a\
\        this is the text I want to add.
}
```

sed trims leading space on text to be appended. Adding a backslash `\` at the start of the line prevents this.

In Bash, this would look like something like:

```
sed -e '/"example\.net"/,/also-notify/{
  /also-notify/a\
  \        this is the text I want to add.
  }' named.conf.local
```

Also note that sed uses an older dialect of regular expressions that doesn't support non-greedy quantifies like `*?`.

Comment: I can't seem to get the syntax of {} section right in bash itself. it errors with 'unmatched {'

Comment: I've added an example that I tested in bash. HTH.